# How to import data into the File field using "Import Article" feature?

Tags: knowledge, articles, import

I'm trying to import data per article type. This is using Login>Set up>Administration Set up>Data Management>Import Articles

While doing this I'm getting an error:

> [MESSAGE 5/1/2015 4:33 AM] -- Import Started --
>   [ERROR zip:articleImportGEBSCEXPATContent.zip - 5/1/2015 4:33 AM] Row 2, column GEBSCBAGSArticleAttachment: The D:\GEBSC Phase III\Knowledge Management Data Load\BAGS\3585 CA1.pdf file path is invalid.
>   [MESSAGE 5/1/2015 4:33 AM] The import completed with errors. Articles rejected: 1. Articles loaded: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the full path to the file. You need a relative path to the file in relation to the file inside the ZIP file.

So, if you were importing a folder with this structure

CSV file >Folder A>Files(folder) > thefile.pdf

Your path in the CSV file would be /folder A/Files/thefile.pdf

Comment: [MESSAGE 5/1/2015 5:42 AM] -- Import Started --
[ERROR zip:Folder A.zip - 5/1/2015 5:42 AM] Row 2, column GEBSCBAGSArticleAttachment: The \folder\Folder A\3585 CA1.pdf file path is invalid.
[MESSAGE 5/1/2015 5:42 AM] The import completed with errors. Articles rejected: 1. Articles loaded: 0

Comment: Error is still the same as I tried creating folder structure per your suggestion! where i'm going wrong also instead of using this '/' I'm making use of '\'

Comment: Thank you so very much, PepeFloyd!! It worked for me not yesterday but today :-) Thanks again!!